# Set up non-persistent relation in Doctrine 2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have an object $user that has a one to many relation with $establishment.  I can use:

```
$user->getEstablishments();
```

The user can select a stablishment to work on.  I have this method that I call in the controller:

```
$user->setCurrentEstablishment($establishment);
```

And this one that I call in the view:

```
$establishment = $user->getCurrentEstablishment();
```

I want to be able to call:

```
$user->setCurrentEstablishmentBy Slug($establishment_slug);
```

where the slug is a string, and let the user object look for the establishment.

Doctrine discourages the practice of accessing the Entity Manager inside the Entity object, but I think that using it in the controller is even worse.

I suspect that some special Doctrine annotation exists that takes care of non persistent relations like this, or some method other than serving the Entity Manager through a service should be used here.  Some easy way of referencing other entities from inside the model.

¿Is there any? ¿How could I do that?

Comment: Why do you think using the entity manager in a controller is bad?

Comment: You should to that in controller or in service (for example UserService - you would need to create it).

Comment: It's not that using the entity manager in the controller is bad.  It's that the entity should give you some related data about itself without you having to collect it yourself in the controller.  Just like it gives you the usual persistent relations, It should give you the runtime, non-persistent, relations also, Like, in my example, the related record by slug.  Just my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `Annotation` in Doctrine which could convert slug into object.

What can help You is `ParamConverter`, with it you can automatically convert slug from query into object. But it still must be used in Controller.

Example usage:

```
/**
* @Route("/some-route/{slug}")
* @ParamConverter("object", class="AppBundle:Establishment", options={"id" = "slug", "repository_method" = "findEstablishmentBySlug"})
*/
public function slugAction(Establishment $object)
{
...
```

Docs about param converter: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html

Comment: Am I the only one that think that not being able to do this is just awful?